# How to rollback a release automatically?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We currently have a setup where we schedule a new release definition to be created at 4am every Monday, this then automatically triggers a deployment.

An issue we may face is that one of the deployments may fail, if this happens is there a way to **automatically** roll back the release?